# IFormFile property in .NET Core ViewModel causing stalled AJAX Request

Tags: javascript, c#, node.js, json, asp.net-core

I am giving users the ability to add images for a retail product inside of an Add/Edit Product modal.

### Modal ViewModel:

```
public class ProductModalViewModel
{
    public ProductModalViewModel()
    {
        Product = new ProductDTO();
        Images = new List<ProductImageViewModel>();
    }

    public ProductDTO Product { get; set; }

    public List<ProductImageViewModel> Images { get; set; }
}
```

Each product image is contained in its own ViewModel, as below:

### Image ViewModel:

```
public class ProductImageViewModel
{
    public ProductImageViewModel()
    {
        ProductImage = new ProductImageDTO();
    }

    public ProductImageDTO ProductImage { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Upload)]
    public IFormFile ImageFile { get; set; }
}
```

Upon submitting the form to save the product (and any added images) my request gets hung up and displays "pending" in Chrome Development Tools. My controller action is never reached.

This only happens when I include the ProductImage Fields/ViewModel/Logic in my project. This was not occurring before adding that functionality to the modal, and works fine if I remove all of the ProductImage Fields/ViewModel/Logic then submit again.

Is there something inherently wrong with including my IFormFile inside of a nested ViewModel? Or could this be something else. The rest of my relevent code is below.

### Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult SaveProduct([FromForm]ProductModalViewModel model)
{
    //save code    
}
```

### View (Modal):

```
<form id="formSaveProduct" onsubmit="SaveProduct(event)" enctype="multipart/form-data">
//Other product fields removed for brevity
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <ul class="list-group" id="image-list-group">
                @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Images.Count(); i++)
                {
                    <partial name="_ImageListItem" for="Images[i]" />
                }
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

### PartialView (ProductImage):

```
<li class="list-group-item my-1">
    <input type="hidden" asp-for="ProductImage.Id" class="image-id" />
    <input type="hidden" asp-for="ProductImage.ProductId" class="image-productid" />

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-3">
            <input type="text" readonly asp-for="ProductImage.Order" class="image-order" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-6">
            <img src="..\@Model.ProductImage.Path" class="image-display" />
        </div>
    </div>
</li>
```

### Script:

```
function SaveProduct(e) {

    e.preventDefault();  // prevent standard form submission

    $.ajax({
        url: "@Url.Action("SaveProduct", "ProductManagement", new { Area = "Admin" })",
        method: "post",
        data: new FormData($('#formSaveProduct')[0]),
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        cache: false,
        success: function (result) {
            //removed for brevity
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: for Ajax function, add contentType: multipart/form-data and try again, Im not sure whether this help or not.

Comment: What is the defination for `ProductImageDTO`? Is there any demo to reproduce your issue? Is there any error in the web developer console tab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question was answered wonderfully in my conceptual question in the following post:

[IFormFile as a Nested ViewModel Property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56347606/iformfile-as-a-nested-viewmodel-property)

Answer (score 1):

First you dont need this

```
[DataType(DataType.Upload)]
public IFormFile ImageFile { get; set; }
```

so you can change your code to

```
 public IFormFile ImageFile { get; set; }
```

And in your script you should add `contentType`

```
function SaveProduct(e) {

    e.preventDefault();  // prevent standard form submission

    $.ajax({
        url: "@Url.Action("SaveProduct", "ProductManagement", new { Area = "Admin" })",
        method: "post",
        data: new FormData($('#formSaveProduct')[0]),
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        cache: false,
        contentType: "multipart/form-data", //here
        success: function (result) {
            if (result.success) {
                $("#exampleModal").modal('toggle');
                location.reload();
            }
            else {
                $(".modal-body").html(result);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I believe adding the contentType causes [FromForm] in my controller action to no longer function. The request is no longer stalling, but the controller action is never reached. Should I be making changes to the action as well?

Comment: i think you can use [FromBody]